# IntellijIdea: FileNotFoundException for vim TOhtml

Tags: java, vim

I was trying to use https://developer.rackspace.com/blog/displaying-prepared-code-with-syntax-highlighting-on-android/ to display some code in html, so I wrote a custom formatter in Java, which has, among other things, this procedure:

```
String code2html( String s ) throws Exception {
    if ( s == null || s.length() == 0 ) return "";
    String t;
    PrintWriter w = new PrintWriter(Konst.FPATH+"tmp.txt","UTF-8");
    w.println(s);
    w.close();
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process pr = rt.exec("vim -c \"let html_use_css=0\" -c \"TOhtml\" -c \"w\" "+Konst.FPATH+"tmp.txt.html"+" -c \"wq\" -c \"q\" "+Konst.FPATH+"tmp.txt");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(Konst.FPATH+"tmp.txt.html"));
    while ( (t=b.readLine())!=null && !(t.length()>=5&&t.substring(0,5).equals("<body")) );
    do {sb.append(t+"\n");} while ( (t=b.readLine())!=null && !(t.length()>=6&&t.substring(0,6).equals("</body")) );
    sb.append(t);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

However, I get `FileNotFoundException` for tmp.txt.html file, although the tmp.txt is created allright. Running the above vim command from commandline produces the desired result. What can be done?

EDIT: I added `int retVal = pr.exitValue()` and got `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: process hasn't exited`

EDIT: Ha, I've read this wonderful document: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html?page=2, implemented their recipe for dealing with this problem, and what I get is

```
ERROR>Vim: Warning: Output is not to a terminal
ERROR>Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal
```

Comment: //konst.FPATH+"tmp.txt"//  What is the value of 'konst.FPATH'? Is the file in same path? //Running the above vim command // Which command you ran?

Comment: Konst.FPATH is a valid path within the project, the command is "vim -c "let html_use_css=0" ..."

Comment: I added int retVal = pr.waitFor(), and the process hangs -- I try to print retVal, and there is nothing on the run console.

Comment: //Running the above vim command from commandline produces the desired result// Can you edit the line starting with `rt.exec(` ? May be a wrong quote or slashes missing! Please post the command here.

Comment: vim -c "let html_use_css=0" -c "TOhtml" -c "wq" -c "q" -c "q" /someDirectory/tmp.txt -- tmp.txt is inside "someDirectory". Running this from commandline does produce tmp.txt.html inside "someDirectory", just try for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Bram Moolenaar answers similar question on http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/Vim-Warning-Output-is-not-to-a-terminal-td4648615.html
He says "If both input and output are redirected, you are really stuck".
I found a workaround by using gvim rather than terminal vim, and rewriting my above code as

```
String code2html( String s ) throws Exception {
        if ( s == null || s.length() == 0 ) return "";
        String t;
        PrintWriter w = new PrintWriter(Konst.FPATH+"tmp.txt","UTF-8");
        w.println(s);
        w.close();
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        String T;
        try {
            Process pr = rt.exec(T = "gvim -c \"let html_use_css=0\" -c \"TOhtml\" -c \"wqx\" -c \"q\" -c \"q\" " + Konst.FPATH + "tmp.txt");
            FileOutputStream fos;

            StreamGobbler errorGobbler = new StreamGobbler(pr.getErrorStream(),"ERROR");
            StreamGobbler outputGobbler = new StreamGobbler(pr.getInputStream(),"OUTPUT",fos=new FileOutputStream(Konst.FPATH+"garbage.out"));

            errorGobbler.start();
            outputGobbler.start();

            int exitVal = pr.waitFor();
            System.out.println("ExitValue: "+exitVal);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(Konst.FPATH + "tmp.txt.html"));
            while ((t = b.readLine()) != null && !(t.length() >= 5 && t.substring(0, 5).equals("<body"))) ;
            do {
                sb.append(t + "\n");
            } while ((t = b.readLine()) != null && !(t.length() >= 6 && t.substring(0, 6).equals("</body")));
            sb.append(t);
            return sb.toString();
        }
        catch ( Throwable e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }`
```